# Calculate Mysql Ndb Cluster table size

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

Im trying to calculate table row size for my table in mysql ndb cluster. As documentation says that value consist of IndexMemory + DataMemory + 16 bytes per row overhead + 128 bytes per DataMemory page.

My NDB Cluster configuration: Server version: 5.6.25-ndb-7.4.7-cluster-gpl-log MySQL Cluster Community Server (GPL)

> NoOfReplica: 1
>
> Node count: 1
>
> DataMemory: 2Gb
>
> IndexMemory: 512Mb
>
> Other defaults.
>
> All data stored in RAM.

I have used test table to fill ndb cluster up to its limit.

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` ( 
`id`bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,   
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE=ndbcluster AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

**My calculation for this table :**

> DataMemory: 8(bigint)+8(bigint)+10(ordered index for primary key)+16(overhead) = 42 bytes
>
> IndexMemory: 25(hash index for primary key) = 25 bytes

**ndb_mgm> ALL report memory**

> Node 11: Data usage is 95%(62260 32K pages of total 65536)
>
> Node 11: Index usage is 76%(50017 8K pages of total 65600)
>
> Row count: 28430087

**But afterall when table was full. Real numbers is:**

> MemoryData: 62260*32578 / 28430087 = ~71 bytes
>
> IndexMemory: 50017*8192 / 28430087 = ~14.4 bytes

**ndb_size.pl says next:**

```
  DataMemory for Columns (* means varsized DataMemory):
                  Column Name                 Type  Varsized   Key       4.1        5.0        5.1 
                           id           bigint(20)             PRI         8          8          8 
                      user_id           bigint(20)                         8          8          8 
                                                                          --         --         -- 


    Summary (for THIS table):
                                     4.1        5.0        5.1 
        Fixed Overhead DM/Row         12         12         16 
               NULL Bytes/Row          0          0          0 
               DataMemory/Row         28         28         32  (Includes overhead, bitmap and indexes)
    
      Varsize Overhead DM/Row          0          0          8 
       Varsize NULL Bytes/Row          0          0          0 
           Avg Varsize DM/Row          0          0          0 
    
                     No. Rows          6          6          6 

        Rows/32kb DM Page       1165       1165       1020 
Fixedsize DataMemory (KB)         32         32         32 

Rows/32kb Varsize DM Page          0          0          0 
  Varsize DataMemory (KB)          0          0          0 

         Rows/8kb IM Page        248        512        512 
         IndexMemory (KB)          8          8          8
```

I didnt count 128 byte per 32kb page overhead but it is doesnt matter when there such a difference. Where i am wrong?